# c++ multidimensional sorting

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have written a basic program that collects student names and answers and automatically scores them.  At the end I'd like to sort the scores in descending order with the corresponding names.  I understand how to sort the scores but not in combination with the student names.  This is what I have so far.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //declare variables
    char choice;
    string studentName;
    vector<char> answers;
    vector<string> names;
    int getStudents();
    int getQuestions();

    //calls function to get number of questions
    int questions = getQuestions();

    //Get answers
    for (int i = 0; i < questions; ++i) {
        cout << "What is the answer for question " << i + 1 << endl;
        cin >> choice;
        answers.push_back(choice);
    }

    //Get number of students
    int students = getStudents();

    //Get student names
    for (int i = 0; i < students; i++) {
        cout << "Student " << i + 1 << ", what is your name?" << endl;
        cin >> studentName;
        names.push_back(studentName);
    }

    int score = 0;
    char studentAnswer;
    vector<char> userAnswer;
    vector<float> finalScore;

    //gets student answers
    for (int i = 0; i < students; i++) {
        score = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < questions; j++) {
            cout << names[i] << ", what is your answer for question " << j + 1 << "?" << endl;
            cin >> studentAnswer;
            userAnswer.push_back(studentAnswer);
            if (userAnswer[i*questions+j] == answers[j])
                score = score + 1;
        }
        finalScore.push_back(score);
    }

    //outputs scores
    std::sort(finalScore.begin(), finalScore.end());
    for (int i = 0; i < students; i++) {
        cout << names[i] << " scored " << finalScore[i] << " out of " << questions <<
            " or " << (finalScore[i] / questions) * 100 << "%" << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

//function to get number of questions
int getQuestions()
{
    int questions;
    cout << "How many questions are there?" << endl;
    cin >> questions;
    return questions;
}

//function to get number of students
int getStudents()
{
    int students;
    cout << "How many students are there?" << endl;
    cin >> students;
    return students;
}
```

Right now, it sorts the scores in descending orders but the names that are output with the scores are incorrect.

Comment: Here you want to learn about structs/classes to aggregate the notion of a `Student` into a single data type that you can store and sort together, as well as possibly how to use a comparator predicate with `std::sort`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I am new to programming and I do not think we have covered structs or classes.  When I emailed my prof to inquire about how to sort, this was his reply

"The output arrays would look similar to <score> <name> for the descending score sort, and <name> <score> for the ascending name sort.

The simplest way to accommodate this is to concatenate the values when building a vector (with a switch or IF statement to accommodate any single digit scores in the event that double digit scores exist, etc.)"

I do not understand what he means.

Comment: If you haven't learned about structs or classes yet, what you can do instead is sort an array of _indices_ into those vectors. Then you want to use a custom comparator with `std::sort` which sorts the scores in descending order (using greater than). After that, you use the sorted indices to look up the names and scores for each student after sorting those indices based on the scores.

Comment: So basically you want to have an additional `std::vector<int>` in this case which has as many entries as there are students. Initially it can just be filled with `0,1,2,..,n-1` where `n` is the number of students. Then you call `std::sort` on that, but with a custom comparator that looks at the student scores instead of those indices. It's a bit easier if you know how to use `structs` at a basic level -- kind of weird to be dealing with sorting data with multiple fields before learning about structs/classes, but it's doable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to somehow 'connect' student name with his/her score. A very easy and straightforward way is to create a struct, i.e.

```
typedef struct Student
{
    string student_name_;
    float student_score_;
} Student;
```

Next you need to define a Compare function (look here for an example: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) so that you can use `std:sort` to sort a vector of `Student`s. Your Compare function could like like this:

```
bool myCompareFunction ( Student a, Student b) 
{ 
    return (a.student_score_ < b.student_score_);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep the spirit of what you are doing, you can make a vector of pairs, here is a code example:

```
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

int main()
{
  std::vector< std::pair<double,std::string> > my_student_list; //  first element is the grade, second is the name
  std::pair<double,std::string>  student1(2.,"name1"),student2(2.,"name2"),student3(1.,"name3");
  my_student_list.push_back(student1);
  my_student_list.push_back(student2);
  my_student_list.push_back(student3);

  std::sort(my_student_list.begin(),my_student_list.end()); // sort by grade

  // loop over the vector to print the sorted list
  for(std::vector< std::pair<double,std::string> >::iterator iterator = my_student_list.begin(); iterator != my_student_list.end(); iterator++){
    // iterator->second is the name, and iterator->first the associated grade
    std::cout << iterator->second << " " << iterator->first << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If i understand correctly, you can not create a vector of pairs with 2 different variable types?  Am I incorrect about that?

Comment: @RyanA Here the pair consists of a double and a std::string. The std::vector stores a pair. In this case a std::pair<double,std::string>. The vector can store any kind of pair.